# Startup script not executing after reboot on Solaris

Tags: solaris

I have a command to start Apache in `/etc/rc3.d` that does not execute when the server reboots.  The script is named `S75Apache2`.  Someone has speculated that this is because the link has a capital "A" in the name and it might work if renamed to `S75apache2`.

Can anyone confirm?  I've searched for documentation but cannot find an answer.  I can't really test this without rebooting the server again (which I'd rather not do).

Comment: What version of Solaris is it? If it's >= 10 you probably want an SMF service instead (I don't know if SMF was available on earlier versions).

Comment: We are on Solaris 10.

Comment: Then I would recommend creating an SMF service. (I assume you're not using the apache that comes with S10, since it wouldn't have legacy start up scripts). Check out [manifold](http://code.google.com/p/manifold/) for easy SMF creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solaris init scripts are a pain.  The capital-A doesn't matter, there's a script in `/etc/rc.d` that finds every file in `/etc/rc3.d` that starts with 'S' and runs them in numerical order.

That leaves you with Starting From The Basics:

1. Is `/etc/rc3.d/S75Apache2` set executable?
2. Does that script have a '#!' line?  Is the line correct (no
   non-printing bytes, etc)?
3. If it's a bash or ksh script run it as `ksh -n /etc/rc3.d/S75Apache2
   start`.  That will tell you if it has syntax errors.
4. If you can run that script as root, try it: `/etc/rc3.d/S75Apache2 
   start` and `/etc/rc3.d/S75Apache2  stop`  Check carefully to see if
   it starts`httpd` and stops `httpd`.  At the very least run the script with 'start' and 'stop' arguments yourself.  Use `set -x` to see what the script does at run time.  Check to see if what it does matches what you believe it does.
5. Read `/etc/rc3.d/S75Apache2` carefully.  `PATH` is sparsely
   populated at boot, and your script may not know where some
   executables are at boot time, but  might when run after booting.  Try not
   to assume too much - files might not exist that you think exist, 
   things like that.
6. Ensure that a `KnnApache2` script doesn't exist in `/etc/rc3.d`. I beliee that the Solaris `init` will run (for example) `K76Apache2  stop` when it transitions from run level 3 to run level 5.
7. Ensure that the script changes user ID appropriately.  This probably isn't important for Apache, given that your script probably just calls `apachectl start` with some prologue commands, but if you run `http` directly, make sure that the resulting `httpd` process has the correct user ID.  Use `sudo` or something in the script to get it right.

Comment: The entry is a link to /etc/init.d/apache2, which is set executable (1).  The first line is '#!/sbin/sh' and seems correct (2).  After rebooting, we start Apache manually as root using the same link (i.e. /etc/rc3.d/S75Apache2 start) (4).  All the required paths are defined in the script itself (5). Can you think of anything else to check?

Comment: Is run level 3 appropriate?  I can't recall what Solaris run level 3 means.  Has the kernel started up user-level networking at that point?  Maybe run-leve 5 is better?  I don't have a Solaris machine to check on this stuff.

Comment: @BruceEdiger - On Solaris run level 3 is multi-user, run level 5 is power-off, so 3 is definitely much better than 5.   User-level networking is started during run level 2, so is ready by the time 3 is entered.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out there WAS a bug in the startup script: the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable was not set properly.  Defining that in the script will fix the problem.

For future reference, there is a log file that contains startup messages which contained the error that led to solving our problem.  The file is:

```
/var/svc/log/milestone-multi-user-server:default.log
```

I found a reference to this in the /etc/rc3.d/README file. Another day, another nugget of knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

Have you rolled your own Apache (i.e. compiled it from source code) or are you simply using the Apache that comes pre-installed with Solaris 10 ?

Well it doesn't really matter, if you are on Solaris 10 (or later) as you say you are **you should not be using Solaris init scripts at all**, you should be using SMF. (yes, technically init scripts are still supported, but as you point out they are a pain, and SMF is much better)

To start (now, and also automatically after a re-boot) the Apache 2.2 Web Server that comes pre-inststalled with Solaris 10 then simply do this:

```
svcadm  enable /network/http:apache2
```

If you have rolled your own Apache then you need to create a SMF manifest, import the manifest and off you go. Just Google for "SMF Solaris" and you will find lots of recipes.